# Chrominance similarity inof images in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am currently doing a project on image quality assessment and implementing the following paper

**A New Method for Color Image Quality Assessment - Niveditta Thakur and Swapna Devi, International Journal of Computer Applications, February 2011**

I have implemented most of the code but struggling to understand how to calculate the color similarity. I converted the RGB image to HSI , and now I want to extract chrominance information from it in a single plane and do the similarity measure.

Here is what i did:

```
hsi=rgb2hsi(I);
H = hsi(:,:,1); % seperate Saturation & Intensity to give hue of image
S = hsi(:,:,2); % Seperate Hue & Intensity to give Saturation of image
I = hsi(:,:,3); % Seperate Hue & saturation to give Intensity/grayscale image
h_n=cat(3,H,S,x_z);
g_n=rgb2gray(h_n);
k=1;
for x=1:factor:s1-2
    for y=1:factor:s2-2
        for  i=0:factor-1
            for j=0:factor-1
                n1((i+1),(j+1),k)=g_n((x+i),(y+j),1);
            end
        end
        k=k+1;
    end
end

for p=1:3072
    mh1(p)=mean2(n1(:,:,p));
end
```

I ran this on both the distorted and test image. The similarity measure was computed as follows:

```
hue=[((2*(mh1*mh2)))]/[(((mh1)^2+(mh2)^2))];
```

But I still don't have my desired results.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please note that x_z is x_z=zeros(384,512); where 384 & 512 are image dimensions